# Python Pandas: df =pd.read_csv('olympics.csv')

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm asking help how to use the Python command: `df=pd.read_csv('olympics.csv')`. My intention is to use pandas to read this file, and determine how many countries have won more than 1 Gold medal.

Assumption: 'olympics.csv' resides in same directory as .py file. I tried #using the entire path inside parentheses, but that had no effect

> **#('/Users/myname/temp/intro_ds/week2/olympics.csv')**

The error I receive when running this file in Bash is: KeyError:'Gold'
I'm using Python 2.7.10 on a MacBook, Unix

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv')
only_gold = df.where(df['Gold'] > 0)        
print only_gold()
```

Comment: Can you give the layout of your CSV  file? Perhaps paste the header and first row or 2. The problem is not with the path but rather that you are trying to read a column name that it does not think is there.

Comment: Sounds like `Gold` is not a column header, things are case sensitive perhaps `gold`.

Comment: Do you have any success with just reading the csv file? Try to see what df is looking like after you import, before you try the rest of the code, you might need to adjust data before you start your analysis. Some of the changes you might need are the other parameters for the pd.read_csv(), like index_col and skiprows.

Comment: Why dont you try subsetting later on? df['Gold'] will give you all the rows/countries that have gold medals. I am assuming that Jeff Carey's comment is solved

Comment: what do you get from running `cols = df.columns`?

Comment: Why do you use () for calling only_gold

Comment: Hi Jeff,  I think you're right. The original table does not have the word 'Gold' in it; however, that's what we were taught to search for the category in the Coursera class, Applied Data Science in Python.  Following is the link to the original website and the first few rows of the table. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table

Answer (score 3):

**[olympics.csv](http://pastebin.com/index/Gu4crXgK)** has no column with name **Gold**, **Silver** or **Bronze** when you first convert it to csv. You have to rename column headers, skip some unnecessary rows and make an index.

To read **[olympics.csv](http://pastebin.com/index/Gu4crXgK)**, skip rows (if you need to, depends on your csv formatting) and Make an index on Team names.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv', skiprows=1, index_col=0)
df.head()
```

This should give you results like this which has **01!**, **02!** instead of **Gold**, **Silver** in columns header.

[image]

To rename columns header to **Gold**, **Silver** and **Bronze** from **01!**, **02!** and **03!**. Run the following

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col[:2]=='01':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Gold'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:2]=='02':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Silver'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:2]=='03':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Bronze'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:1]=='№':
        df.rename(columns={col:'#'+col[1:]}, inplace=True)

df.head()
```

[image]

Now you can make query like

```
df['Gold'] #for summer olympics Gold medals
df['Gold.1'] #for winter olympics Gold medals
df['Gold.2'] #for combined summer+winter Gold medals
```

Convert [All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table) table to [csv](http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm)

Comment: Thank you LaL ZaDa! Yes, I also discovered later the same day that I had failed to review carefully the 'rename' function of pandas.